# Razor does not render when if clause is used

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Why does the razor html not work?

**WORKS NOT**

```
@if (Model.Devices.Any())
{

      foreach (var device in Model.Devices)
    {

        Html.Partial(MVC.Devices.Refrigerator.Views.GroupedRefrigerators, device);

    }
}
else
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        @(Html.Raw(xxxx)
    </div>
}
```

**WORKS**

```
  @foreach (var device in Model.Devices)
        {

            @Html.Partial(MVC.Devices.Refrigerator.Views.GroupedRefrigerators, device);

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you're in a code block, calling `Html.Partial` just returns the resulting string to memory. But you're not storing it or doing anything with it.

Calling `@Html.Partial`, however, makes it inject the resulting string onto the page.

You could fix the first block by adding some html element to surround the partial:

```
foreach (var device in Model.Devices)
{
    <div>
        @Html.Partial(MVC.Devices.Refrigerator.Views.GroupedRefrigerators, device);
    </div>
}
```

As @Richard pointed out, you could also use `@:` or `<text>` instead of a `<div>` to make it render.

Comment: You don't need to use HTML to get out of a code block, you can use [`@:` or `<text>.....</text>`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do it as well, this was just one suggestion.